# radio box selected item on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

i'm wonder how could i set up selected item checked when i'm using radio button list

my sample code look like this

```
<div ng-repeat="vehicle in filteredVehicle">
<input type="radio" name="radiog_lite" id="radio_{{$index}}" class="css-checkbox" ng-value="vehicle" ng-model="$parent.selectedVehicle" ng-disabled="vehicle.enable == '0'" />
<label for="radio_{{$index}}" class="css-label radGroup1" ng-if="vehicle.enable == '1'"></label>
<h5>{{vehicle.vehicleTypeName}}</h5>
```

below i have created plunker please help me to fix the selected item
selected vehicle is on `$scope.selectedVehicle`

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zaq4yNDO6rtXV17W2Ag7?p=preview)**

Thanks

Comment: i need to checked the radio button when loading according to `$scope.selectedvehicle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the `selectedVehicle` with the object with in the array. The reason behind it is that angular add `$$hashKey` to every object.

*Use*

```
$scope.selectedVehicle = {};
$scope.filteredVehicle = {};

$http.get('data.json').then(function(d){
    angular.forEach(d.data.vehicleType, function(value, key) {
          if(value.vehicleTypeID ==  d.data.selected.vehicleTypeID){
            $scope.selectedVehicle = value;
          }
    });
    $scope.filteredVehicle = d.data.vehicleType;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pvZYPM69GHQJhrm4TWJp?p=preview)